# Getting a list of statics on an ES6 class

Tags: javascript, class, properties, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Given an ES6 class, how can I inspect it to determine its gettable static properties and methods?

In ES5 determining the statics attached to a class (it's constructor) was as simple as iterating over the properties of the function. In ES6, is appears there is some magic going on that doesn't expose them as such.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, all methods of `class`es are non-enumerable by default.

You still can iterate them using [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). Filter out `.prototype`, `.name` and `.length` (or just everything that is not a function). To include inherited static methods, you will have to walk the prototype chain explicitly (using `Object.getPrototypeOf`).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get a dynamic list of standard class property names (so that you can filter them out of your list of static members), you can simply get the property names from an empty class:

```js
const standardClassProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(class _{});

// ["length", "prototype", "name"]
```

This will produce a reasonably future-proof array that will dynamically adapt to changes to the standard, especially the addition of new standard static properties.

```js
class Foo {
    static bar() {}
}

function isOwnStaticMember(propName) {
    return !standardClassProps.includes(propName);
}

const staticMembers = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Foo ).filter(isOwnStaticMember);

// ["bar"]
```