# How to disassemble ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to tear an ES6 class down to individual functions?

```
class ParentClass {
}
class MyClass extends ParentClass {
    static get STATIC_GETTER() {
    }
    static set STATIC_SETTER(value) {
    }
    static STATIC_METHOD() {
    }
    get GETTER() {
    }
    set SETTER(value) {
    }
    METHOD1() {
    }
    METHOD2() {
    }
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

I'd like to print to the console something like:

```
The class "MyClass"
extends class: ParentClass
has:
a constructor
static getters: STATIC_GETTER
static setters: STATIC_SETTER
static method: STATIC_METHOD
getters: GETTER
setters: SETTER
methods: METHOD1,METHOD2
```

Comment: In the same way you'd "disassemble" an ES5 class - there's not much more than syntactic sugar. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What about getters and setters?

Comment: They're just accessor properties on the prototype/constructor, as always. You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`.

Comment: @bergi 3 years later I found that ES5 an ES6 classes should be decomposed differently.

Comment: What do you think is different (apart from the syntax)?

Comment: It's in my answer below. Main difference - "static properties" inheritance. Another thing - using `Reflect` instead of `Object` as more future proof API.

Comment: You misunderstand the purpose of `Reflect`. It is not a "more future proof API", it only provides the default implementations for proxy traps and nothing else. You should continue to use the normal `Object` methods if you're not working with proxies.

Comment: Yes, handling inherited static properties is good, but following the constructor prototype chain does work on ES5 classes as well - it just will only find the methods inherited from `Function.prototype`.

Comment: @Bergi I wish someone would have answered about how to properly filter properties out. Namely ignore length, name, prototype properties. It's not as trivial as ES5 for sure.

Comment: Hm, if you were only looking for static properties I would have pointed you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33069692/1048572) :-) Notice that you have to filter out these three for ES5 as well (also `.arguments`, `.arity`, `.displayName` and `.caller`).

Comment: A relevant quote from here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1
"Let’s stop judging users for not knowing things."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike ES5 the ES6 classes were standardized. As well as prototype linkage.

In ES6 there are two prototype chains actually, unlike ES5.

- Child->Parent **.prototype** link. (Used for object instances.)
- Child->Parent **.constructor** link. (Used for class static properties.)

In order to retrieve them all in ES6 it is recommended to use global `Reflect` JS API.

Here is how you retrieve all the instance methods/properties of a class and **all its parents**.

```
function classMethods(ctor) {
  if (ctor === Function.prototype) return {};
  return Reflect.ownKeys(ctor.prototype).reduce((methods, k) => {
    if (k !== 'constructor') {
      methods[k] = ctor.prototype[k];
    }
    return methods;
  }, classMethods(ctor.__proto__))
}
```

To retrieve all the static methods/properties you need to traverse the constructor itself.

```
function classStaticProperties(ctor) {
  if (ctor === Function.prototype) return {};
  return Reflect.ownKeys(ctor).reduce((statics, k) => {
    if (k !== 'length' && k !== 'name' && k !== 'prototype') {
      statics[k] = ctor[k];
    }
    return statics;
  }, classStaticProperties(ctor.__proto__));
}
```

Usage:

```
const allMethods = classMethods(MyChildClass);
const allStaticProperties = classStaticProperties(MyChildClass);
```

Comment: Btw, you should always use `getPrototypeOf` (either on `Object` or `Reflect`), not the deprecated `.__proto__` getter.