# How do I upgrade a TypeScript ES5 Class decorator that wraps all methods to ES2015/ES6?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, decorator, ecmascript-5

In ES5, to decorate all the methods of a class, I had syntax like this:

```
export function validateArgs(constructor: Function) {
  // copy the methods so that we avoid self referencing.
  const original: Function = Object.assign({}, constructor);
  // iterate over all the static methods in the class
  for (const i in constructor) {
    // wrap them in a method that throws an error if args are not valid
    constructor[i] = function(...args: any[]) {
      if(areArgsValid(args)) {
           return original[i].apply(this, args);
      }
      throw `Args aren't valid`
    };
  }
}
```

```
@validateArgs
class Validator {
    static myThingIsValid(arg1) {
         return !!arg1;
    }
    myOtherThingIsValid(arg1) {
         return !!arg1;
    }
}
```

When I change my tsconfig to a target of ES2015 from ES5, the methods are no longer wrapped with the args validation.

Comment: It is not considered good policy to ask voters to reveal their identity and reasoning. Read here for more [information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not/285777#285777) about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6, the methods of a class are not enumerable. In ES5, classes were compiled down to functions and those methods are enumerable. So after upgrading, the following no longer iterated over methods:

```
for (const i in constructor) { ... }
```

The solution comes partly from here: [Getting a list of statics on an ES6 class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069692/getting-a-list-of-statics-on-an-es6-class)

```
// clone the class
const original: Function = Object.assign( Object.create( Object.getPrototypeOf(constructor)), constructor);
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(constructor)
    .filter(prop => typeof prop === 'function')
    .forEach(val => {
        // copy the static method since it's not copied from the class clone
        original[i] = constructor[i];
        ....
    })
```

However, that will only give you static methods. To get all methods, you need something like:

```
[
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(constructor), 
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(constructor.prototype)
]
.filter(prop => typeof (constructor[prop] || constructor.prototype[prop]) === 'function')
.forEach(val => ...)
```

Comment: Weird that this was downvoted. Here, have my upvote! 